# Swift documentation not showing in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

Not sure if this is a know issue since I could find nothing but a [single radar](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2017/10/radar-xcode-quick-help-no-longer-shows-documentation-from-imported-module/).

It seems that Swift documentation are not showing in the '`Quick Help`' when imported to `Objective C`.

Example Swift code:

```
/// This is a comment
@objc static func foo() {

}
```

If I `Opt+Click` it (in Swift), it will show the Quick Help. However, I cannot get it to show in Objective C class, I get 'No Quick Help'.

The Auto-Completion actually works and shows the 'summary' as you type. But seems to not work for the other Quick Help (`right inspector or Opt+click`).

The reverse *does* works. An Objective C documentations are showing in Swift.

Cannot remember if it ever worked. Is this a bug? Expected in the future? Workarounds?